# How can I set up an Android phone as a webcam in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, android, webcam

I'm a beginning Ubuntu user, and would like to follow the instructions left by Idias in the link below. But I don't understand this step:

5. Find the drivers for your device. This page provides links to most manufacturers websites: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers. You can also search Google “ADB Drivers for ___”

All the drivers I find are windows drivers. Where do you find Ubuntu drivers? Or does the driver go on the phone? I'm using a Neffos X1 Lite. Thanks in advance

[Can I use an Android phone as webcam for an Ubuntu device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235731/can-i-use-an-android-phone-as-webcam-for-an-ubuntu-device)

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in another solution, here's one:
You can use OBS Studio for Linux, which is pretty neat because you can also benefit from all the other nice OBS features. Of course you have to install OBS Studio first and if you're not familiar with how OBS works, have a look at a quick tutorial on yt or so. Then I installed the android app "IP Webcam" on my phone. With the app you can start "broadcasting" your phone's video signal in your wireless network. With your computer and your smartphone in the same wireless network, you just add an browser source in OBS with the "website" (an IP adress) given to you by IP Webcam once you started the streaming. And that's it! Got it to work in about three minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following command in a terminal

```
sudo apt install adb
```

You will have to `Enable USB Debugging` in the Android settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, I already have adb installed.  What I don't understand is where to find the drivers for my phone.  Can I install dll files intended for windows?  Are there Linux specific drivers out there somewhere?

Comment: Usually you don't need to find drivers for Android phones. Once ADB is installed, Ubuntu automatically loads the driver, and your phone should work with Droidcam (at least, that worked for me without manually searching for drivers). Since ADB is installed, just follow these steps https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux/

Comment: Thank you again for your help, I'm really a beginner.  How do I do this step: "1. Ensure the following dependencies are installed (using apt-get, yum, etc.): gcc make linux-headers-`uname -r`"  I don't know how to use apt-get or yum

Comment: Open a terminal, and enter the command 

```sudo apt install gcc make linux-headers-`uname -r` ```