# How can I use WO-Mic in Ubuntu via USB?

Tags: sound, microphone

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (64-bit).
I want to use my android as microphone in my PC using USB cable.
When I searched on Google for the same, I found WO-Mic and installed it as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889164/use-phone-as-microphone-in-linux). But it was not described there how can I use it over USB. I also visited the [WO-Mic website](https://wolicheng.com/womic/wo_mic_linux.html) but there was nothing about how to use it over USB.
Please help...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply connect your phone with USB to your PC. Both the phone and PC should be on same network.
Now, start the server and pass the IP address of the WO-Mic server on the phone to the Wo-mic script on Ubuntu:

```
$ ./micclient-x86_64.AppImage 192.168.181.148
```

However, it connects for a small time and gives the following error:

```
Connecting... 
Connected     
Disconencting...
No audio data is received. Please change your firewall setting to unblock UDP port 49152.
```

[Wo-mic client error with USB on Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVPLy.png)