# How do I install mic_over_mumble?

Tags: sound, permissions, microphone

I'm a lifetime Windows user and I just installed Ubuntu.

I need to use my phone as a mic.

I already found one solution: [Use phone as microphone in Linux](https://askubuntu.com/a/1105685)

I did steps 1 and 2 without any problems, but I have no idea what to do in step 3. It says:

> Copy mic_over_mumble anywhere - it will use ~/.mic_over_mumble as configuration directory. Don't forget to make it executable (chmod +x mic_over_mumble).

I installed the 3 things from steps 1 and 2 with the command line. I didn't download any file or anything. Where is the "mic_over_mumble" file that is referenced? I don't see anything in my download folder. Also, please explain to me how to use `~/.mic_over_mumble` as configuration directory and how to make it executable.

Comment: do I download "mic over mumble master.zip" , is that the one? sorry I don't use github either.

Comment: You can just use `git clone` to download it. See the answer below.

Comment: As far as the configuration directory is concerned, `~/.mic_over_mumble` should automatically create itself the first time you run the script. Because the name starts with a period, it will be hidden so you will need to enable hidden files in your file manager or use `ls -a` to show the hidden files/directories in the terminal. There should be a configuration file in this directory. However, it appears that this file is automatically created based on the settings you choose. This way, you can copy the file to a different user to transfer your settings or use a copy of the file as a backup.

Comment: There's almost always a configuration file for everything. You can simply leave the file alone and your settings will automatically update the file for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run the following commands.

**First**, install `git` and clone mic_over_mumble:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
cd
git clone https://github.com/pzmarzly/mic_over_mumble
```

**Now**, you will have a new directory (folder) named `mic_over_mumble.git`. This new directory will contain the `mic_over_mumble` script.

**Next**, to copy the `mic_over_mumble` script to your user's home directory, use the `cp` command like this:

```
cp ./mic_over_mumble.git/mic_over_mumble ~/
```

**Also**, the other answer forgot to make the file executable so run the following command:

```
chmod +x ~/mic_over_mumble
```

**Finally**, you can run the script from your user's home directory like this:

```
./mic_over_mumble
```

**Alternatively**, you can call the script from any directory by specifying your user's home directory (`~/`):

```
~/mic_over_mumble
```

Comment: Alternatively, one could put the `mic_over_mumble` script into `~/bin`: `mkdir ~/bin`, `cp ./mic_over_mumble.git/mic_over_mumble ~/bin` and open a new shell. After that, `mic_over_mumble` behaves like any command, so you can just run `mic_over_mumble` from the command line without having to care about the location of the script. (This works because in Ubuntu, `$HOME/bin` is added to the `PATH` environment variable if it exists at shell start -- or more exactly: when `~/.profile` is executed.).

Comment: @orithena Yes, copying to `~/.bin` is actually the preferred method. I thought about mentioning it but I decided to just focus on copying the file to help them learn how to copy a file and run a script directly. Personally, I would use your method.

Comment: Then my comment is a "starting point for further reading into a related topic", that's fine with me :)